# How to iterate over elements in a sparse matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am writing a code for an LDPC belief propogation decoder in matlab.
I am following the algorithm specified in:
http://www.ece.umd.edu/~tta/resources/LDPC.pdf page 6.

I want to use sparse matrix toward this goal.
During which i want to iterate over large sized matrix which has only few ones.
My question is how can i iterate over only the ones in the matrix?

I'll be more specific: let's say i have the following matlab code:

```
for row_index = 1 : row_num
    for coloum_index = 1 : col_num
        if parity_check_matrix(row_index, coloum_index)
            messages_llr_matrix(row_index, coloum_index) = ...
                code_word_aprior_prob(coloum_index);
        end
    end
```

This code takes a vector 'code_word_aprior_prob' and assigns it's values to the row in the matrix 'messages_llr_matrix' which are not zeros. Now, i want to perform this using sparse matrix.

parity_check_matrix is a sparse matrix.

Comment: And by iterating sparse matrices you mean... *accessing* sparse matrices? Iteration just indicates the repetition of a process.

Comment: @JJMDriessen - Iterate over elements implies to access each element individually.  It's very commonly used vocabulary... like in C++ where you iterate over elements in a `std::vector` container for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose you have a sparse matrix `S`. You can iterate over its nonzero elements using

```
[ii,jj,ss] = find(S);

for k=length(ii)
   %// A nonzero element of S: ss(k) = S(ii(k),jj(k))
end
```

Although I'm not sure how fast this would be.

In your specific case you would probably be doing

```
[ii,jj] = find(parity_check_matrix);
for k = 1 : length(ii)
   messages_llr_matrix(ii(k), jj(k)) = ...
            code_word_aprior_prob(jj(k));
end
```

Of course you can rename `ii` and `jj` to be `row_index` and `column_index` resp.

Comment: `find` is the right choice. Note that this iterates over all nonzero elements, not over all ones. `[ii,jj] = find(S==1)` would iterate all ones.

Comment: Is there a faster way without a for loop maybe?

Comment: Wauzl? Because this code is to run multiple times thud needs to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

The following does what your code snippet does, but doesn't exactly iterate over a sparse matrix, like the title of the question suggests. Also, I'm not sure if the approach in my other answer is faster or slower than this.

Note that I assume, that `code_word_aprior_prob` is a row vector. Then doing

```
messages_llr_matrix = bsxfun(@times, parity_check_matrix, code_word_aprior_prob)
```

will probably be enough.

Please test out if this actually gives the correct answer and please test out which way is faster, if you are really aiming for speed.

Comment: Hi, i a have a problem with what you proposed. @times is for multipication. I don't need that. please help me.

Comment: Did you test the code? Did you verify that the result is not what you want?